# Does NetBeans have anything like Eclipse's Shift-F2 to bring up PHP Manual page for keyword?

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, netbeans

In Eclipse when you put your cursor on a keyword and press Shift-F2 it brings up the PHP manual page for that keyword.

Is there anything like that in NetBeans?

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+Shift+Space brings up the documentation.

Comment: This is probably the closest you'll get. It has the short description of the function from the PHP page and it also has a clickable link in the popup window.

Comment: Are you sure that link's clickable? I haven't got it to work yet.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you want is ctrl-space ;)

Comment: at least in netbeans 6.8 it also shows the documentation, ctrl+shift+space is not working ...

Comment: fyi on a mac its cmd-shift-space ;)